# Getting "Failure sending request: StatusCode=429 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded" on Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Terraform is throwing an error "Failure sending request: StatusCode=429 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded" when creating over 2000 A and CNAME records on Azure.

Tried Terraform v0.13.5 and v0.14, same error

Using version 2.39 of the azurerm plugin

An example of my terraform code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
#    version="2.39"
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "large-rg"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "dnsrecords.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "arecord" {
        name                = " arecord "
        zone_name           = " dnsrecords.com"
        resource_group_name = "large-rg"
        ttl                 = 300
        records             = ["1.1.1.1"]
}

resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "cname" {
        name                = "cname"
        zone_name           = " dnsrecords.com"
        resource_group_name = "large-rg"
        ttl                 = 300
        record              = "testing.trafficmanager.net."
}
```

Getting this in the logs

```
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: recording 1 dependencies for azurerm_dns_zone.example 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: writing current state object for azurerm_dns_zone.example 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] [walkRefresh] Exiting eval tree: azurerm_dns_zone.example 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] vertex "azurerm_dns_zone.example": visit complete 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] vertex "azurerm_dns_zone.example": dynamic subgraph completed successfully 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] vertex "azurerm_dns_zone.example": visit complete 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] vertex "azurerm_dns_zone.example (expand)": dynamic subgraph completed successfully 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] vertex "azurerm_dns_zone.example (expand)": visit complete 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"] (close)" errored, so skipping 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: removing lock metadata file .terraform.tfstate.lock.info 
2020/12/09 17:11:22 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: unlocked by closing terraform.tfstate 
2020-12-09T17:11:22.725-0800 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.39.0/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.39.0_x5.exe pid=18812 
2020-12-09T17:11:22.725-0800 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

Edit:
I split the records into batches of around 170 records and created its own terraform.tf and folder. I would run `terraform init` then import the exact same resource group and dns zone, in this case `large-rg` and `dnsrecords.com`. Next step was running `terraform plan` then `terraform apply`.

What would happen is that it would first throw the `StatusCode=429` error, but rerunning it would solve the error. Adding a new record to it will also work.

Doing it this way isn't ideal just because of the size of the records. The amount of records will only get larger as time passes.

Looks like a limitation of Terraform.

Edit2:
Nancy Xiong provided a link where the recommended solution is to use multiple smaller state files. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/6866

Comment: I'm just wondering if all these spaces you have in `name` and `zone_name` are intentional or not?

Comment: @Marcin the spacing in `name` and `zone_name` are not intentional, it looks to have been added when copying and pasting. I did try running it with the spaces and it works.

Comment: So did removing spaces solved the issue? If yes, I can provide a short answer for future reference?

Comment: @Marcin No, removing spaces did not resolve the issue. I did update the original post with what I found if I split it up the 2000 records to around 170 each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create all your resources `azurerm_dns_zone` and `azurerm_resource_group` in the same `.tf` file. I suggest instead of hardcode the value, you can change your terraform template like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "large-rg"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "dnsrecords.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_dns_a_record" "arecord" {
        name                = "arecord"
        zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
        resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
        ttl                 = 300
        records             = ["1.1.1.1"]
}

resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "cname" {
        name                = "cname"
        zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.example.name
        resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
        ttl                 = 300
        record              = "testing.trafficmanager.net."
}
```

Also, the `name` value with having spaces is invalid. You can upgrade to

```
Terraform v0.14.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.41.0
```

Comment: originally the terraform code was like that, but I hardcoded it for simplicity. Also updated code to use latest version of terraform and provider

`terraform 
  required_version="0.14.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.41.0"  
    }
  }
}`

Not sure how to fix spacing on this, hope this helps

Comment: Do you mean you create the records in a folder then export the records into the terraform code automatically then the name value with having spaces is invalid? Could you show me the full steps and samples then I could try to follow your process?

Comment: The spacing is not the issue, I tested it out with the code I provided and it works. Also, my code doesn't have the spacing issue, it pasted here like that. I was saying for the `zone_name` and  `resource_group_name` I had it exactly as what you had originally, but when I pasted the code here, I changed it thinking it would be easier to understand. Hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: What I did was create a few folders each with a terraform.tf with 170 records along with terraform and azurerm required_version. With each folder, I would run `terraform init` then import the exact same resource group and dns zone, in this case `large-rg` and `dnsrecords.com`. Next step was running `terraform plan` then `terraform apply`. `terraform apply` would throw a 429 error, but running it again would not. Adding new dns resource is also fine

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/6866) is a similar case, Azure's returning a HTTP 429 because of too many requests being sent (and so we're being forced to wait and retry) which in turn exceeds the default timeout

Comment: Thanks! Although not the answer I wanted to hear, but at least I know what the issue is now.